# Why pressing hot keys in Main Shorts for the second time soes not switch current layout?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Having 2 keyboard layout in my kubuntu 20.04

I set Right Alt hot keys in Main Shorts : https://prnt.sc/6BELdro2eHZc
Opening Advanced tab I see “Switching to another layout” block with “Right Alt” option set : https://prnt.sc/o8uRyOHM7-VE
But if in default english layout I press “Right Alt” key I have ukrainian language set as current. But pressing  “Right Alt” key one more time
my layout did not swithced to englisg as I expeceted. Did I miss some options in my layouts options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the fact that when the Ukrainian layout is active, <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> is dedicated by default to serve as the key to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols. So since <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> conflicts with that other function, it's not a good choice as the shortcut to switch layout.

My primary advice would be to simply choose some other shortcut for layout switching.